# How many different positive values of $x$ will make this statement true: there are exactly $2$ positive two-digit multiples of $x$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

How many different positive values of $x$ will make this statement true: there are exactly $2$ positive two-digit multiples of $x$.

I was thinking that $x$ needs to be any of $49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34$. So there are $16$ values of $x$ that satisfy the statement. We don't include numbers $50$ and up because then the second multiples about be three digits and we don't include numbers $33$ and below because then we'll have more than two multiples for a two digit number. Is this correct or am I misunderstanding this problem?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Why didn't you include $\{ 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33 \}$, they also fit in your statement, $25 × 2 = 50$, $50 × 2 $ is out

Comment: I didn't include them because those numbers aren't exactly $2$ positive two digit multiples of $x$, You can multiply all of them by $1, 2$, and $3$ and get a two digit number.

Comment: @AderinsolaJoshua is this wrong?

Comment: But the number you listed there, if I also multiply by $2$ they are also still two digit numbers

Comment: @AderinsolaJoshua isn't that what we want? Exactly $2$ positive two digit multiples of $x$. Select any number I listed, multiplied by $1$ and $2$ the result is a two digit number. Pick any number greater than the ones I listed and multiplication by $2$ gives a three digit number. Pick the numbers you listed and we can multiply them all by $1, 2$, and $3$ and get a two digit number. That isn't exactly two positive two digit multiples of $x$.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: No, I think you are correct.  $25$ doesn't count for example, because it has $3$ two-digit multiples.

Comment: @ddswsd Based on the question wording, I agree with [RobertTheTutor](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/883326/robertthetutor)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4067672/how-many-different-positive-values-of-x-will-make-this-statement-true-there-a#comment8404162_4067672), and [saulspatz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/235128/saulspatz)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4067672/how-many-different-positive-values-of-x-will-make-this-statement-true-there-a#comment8404289_4067672), i.e., I also think you're correct.